# Adding GPS information to a TIFF image?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have a set of coordinates for the four endpoints of a TIFF image. I want to add those to the image attributes so I can see the GPS location using the properties of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways of doing this using GIS software or scripting/programming, but (in my opinion) the easiest way, requiring no additional software is to use a "world file", which is a secondary file with the same name but a different extension that contains information. It must also be in the same folder as the image file.

Create a file with the exact same name as the tiff image, but use the extension `.tfw` instead of `.tiff`. Put the following information in the image, each on a new line:

```
pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
rotation about y-axis
rotation about x-axis
pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative
x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
```

Example:

```
32.0
0.0
0.0
-32.0
691200.0
4576000.0
```

When you then load the image into a GIS software (this should work on ArcGIS and QGIS at least), it should automatically place the image in the correct location, but you will probably also have to specify its CRS, which will be whichever CRS your original coordinates are in.

[More information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) (including where I got the guide and example from)